# Android Jetpack Compose: How to add some general functionality to all composable functions in my app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an app using Jetpack Compose for learning purposes and I want to add a general click listener to all composable functions in my app. The click listener should log the name of the composable function that was clicked by the user. For example, if the user clicks on a UserDetailItem or the row/icon in it, it should log "UserDetailItem clicked" to the console.

```
@Composable
fun UserDetailItem() {
    Row {
        Text(text = "Hello, world!")
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Home, contentDescription = "Home icon")
    }
}
```

I know how to add a click listener to a specific composable function using the Modifier.clickable modifier, but I don't want to repeat this for every composable function in my app. For the composable where I want an actual click I can override this function and build on top of the logging functionality. Is there a way to add a general click listener to all composable functions in Jetpack Compose? If so, how can I do it?

Apart from clicks is there any guideline to add common behavior for certain composable functions, similar to having a BaseActivity or BaseFragment?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.